How to use itables with Quarto when creating a dashboard in python?
I'm trying to implement itables with Quarto Dashboard. I've been trying to figure it out but I haven't really been able to.
Here how I implemented it so far:
@reactive.calc
def filtered_penguins():
    # Access input values correctly
    selected_species = input.species()
    selected_islands = input.islands()
    
    # Filter the penguins dataset
    data = penguins[penguins["species"].isin(selected_species)]
    data = data[data["island"].isin(selected_islands)]
    return data 

This is where filtered_penguins is coming from.
from itables import show

#| title: Table
@render.table
def dataview():
    data = filtered_penguins()
    return show(data)

I would like it to be dynamic based on specific filters on dashboard, but when I try to preview the dashboard the table doesn't appear.
